# Zero pad a vector in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, zero-pad

I have a vector that contains 5 numbers and I want to pad it with zeros. How can I do it?

```matlab
A = [1 2 3 4 5].';
```

I want the zero padded vector to be like this:

```matlab
A_new = [0 0 0 0 0 1 2 3 4 5].';
```

Also, for another case, I want to assign 1, 3, 4 to matrix `W` as follows, with all else being zeros. The length of `W` is 7. `W = [0 1 0 0 3 0 4]`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use following code

```
newA = [zeros(5,1); A]
```

About another case. You need something like

```
inds = [2 5 7];
elems = [1 3 4];
W = zeros(7,1);
W(inds) = elems
```

Comment: Thank you, would yu please check my edit on the question and answer it plz. @kvorobiev